# Capture arguments of onclick() javascript call using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a selenium script in Java to capture the arguments passed in JavaScript onclick() call/method. Attached is the image in which method/function name is highlighted.

[image: on click method]

In this method there are some arguments/parameters which i want to capture like we capture any CSS selector. I am unable to do this. In the Below attached image, I want to capture arguments such as "content_ids", "content_type", "value", "currency" and "content_name". Kindly suggest me solution.

[image: method parameters]

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that this can be done using Javascript executor since the onclick method is assigned as function to the function name `productAddToCardForm.submit = function(button, url) { ......` in javascript.

```
WebElement button  = driver.findElement(By.Xpath("//button[@title='Add to Bag']"));
// get the onclick function name trimming the "("
String onclickFunctionName = button.getAttribute("onclick").split("(")[0];

// Use javascript executor to get the value of the onclick function
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
// return value of productAddToCardForm.submit
String function  = js.executeScript("return " + onclickFunctionName); // return function(button, url) { ......

// Do String split and matching to extract required values from the function string.
```